# Create mock 3D "space" with forwards and backwards navigation

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

In iOS, I'd like to have a series of items in "space" similar to the way Time Machine works. The "space" would be navigated by a scroll bar like feature on the side of the page. So if the person scrolls up, it would essentially zoom in in the space and objects that were further away will be closer to the reference point. If one zooms out, then those objects will fade into the back and whatever is behind the frame of refrence will come into view. Kind of like [this](http://scaleofuniverse.com/).

I'm open to a variety of solutions. I imagine there's a relatively easy solution within openGL, I just don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Nick Lockwood's iCarousel on [github](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel).  It's a very good component.  The example code he provides uses a custom carousel style very much like what you describe.  You should get there with just a few tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, in OpenGL(ES) is relatively easy to accomplish what you ask, however it may not be equally easy to explain it to someone that is not confident with OpenGL :)

First of all, I may suggest you to take a look at [The Red Book](http://glprogramming.com/red/), the reference guide to OpenGL, or at the [OpenGL Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page). 
To begin, you may do some practice using [GLUT](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/); it will help you taking confidence with OpenGL, providing some high-level API that will let you skip the boring side of setting up an OpenGL context, letting you go directly to the drawing part.

OpenGL ES is a subset of OpenGL, so essentially has the same structure. Once you understood how to use OpenGL shouldn't be so difficult to use OpenGL ES. Of course [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/) is a very important resource.

Now that you know a lot of stuff about OpenGL you should be able to easily understand how your program should be structured. 

You may, for example, keep your view point fixed and translate the world (or viceversa). There is not (of course) a universal solution, especially because the only thing that matters is the final result.

Another solution (maybe equally good, it depends on your needs), may be to simply scale up and down images (representing the objects of your world) to simulate the movement through the object itself.

For example you may use an array to store all of your images and use a slider to set (increase/decrease) the dimension of your image. Once the image becomes too large for the display you may gradually decrease alpha, so that the image behind will slowly appear. Take a look at [UIImageView reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it contains all the API's you need for it.

This may lead you to the loss of 3-dimensionality, but it's probably a simpler/faster solution than learn OpenGL.